# The registered User can login only One time..Then Second time Denied That user

Tags: asp.net

Could anyone give me some suggestion for my problem?

I can register the new user then it is stored in my MYSQL database.

The registered can login only one time,
it can login successfully

then logout and when the same user login, it is denied.

I thought i need to change in web.config..or in some location..but i don't know it

Pls give me some suggestion

Thanks

```
public partial class Account_Login:System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void loginUser_loggedin(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Roles.IsUserInRole("admin"))
    {
        Response.Redirect(@"~/AdminHomePage.aspx");
    }
    else 
     {
        if (Roles.IsUserInRole("customer"))
        {
            Response.Redirect(@"~/testpage.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect(@"~/testpage.aspx");
        }
      }
}    
}
```

Comment: I Think you need to login again on SO and post some code which could helps us to identify something

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint for the login method to see where the problem is?  I reckon this should tell you pretty quickly where the problem is.  At the very least it will help you post more useful code so we can help you.

Comment: Not possible..session always expire during log-out..